# Best practice for having more than a lock object in a class

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the class below, I have to methods which are doing two totally different things which have nothing to do with eachother. But I am using only one lock object in both of them.

My question is, what is the best practice in such scenarios? Having two separate lock objects for each or sharing one (as we are doing here)?

```
class MyClass
{

private static object _lock = new object();

public void DoSomething()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {

    }
}

public void DoSomethingTotallyDifferent()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is: can `DoSomething` or `DoSomethingTotallyDifferent` be called from each other? If so, you can create a deadlock. Maybe it doesn't call each other now, but they might in the future.

My two cents: better be safe than sorry. Use two separate lock variables.

Comment: In addition to that, both methods might be waiting for each other which is absolutely not necessary, since they are doing completely separate things.

Comment: Indeed. When running in parallel that might be an issue too. @Evk

Comment: Why is it better to use 2 separate lock variables ? If we have Method1 which calls Method2 and Method2 which calls Method1 (Thread1 will starts by Method1 and Thread2 by Method2). If they both have a different lock object, they will cause a deadlock too. Am I right ? But with the only one lock object, they shouldn't deadlock, since the second thread will have to wait the end of Method1 before execute Method2. (if it takes the hand as second)

Comment: But aren't two locks more *unsafe* since only then a deadlock becomes possible? I agree with the conclusion but I don't see how that's more safe.

Answer (score 6):

The lock object should be dedicated to the critical resource, not the class.

For example, if your class uses a critical resource `A` in the `DoSomething` method, then there should be a `_lockA` object for it. If `DoSomethingTotallyDifferent` accesses also this resource, then it should use the same lock object. If it accesses an other critical resource `B`, of course it then should lock that corresponding lock object `_lockB`. The methods interfear only, if they have to use the same resource...